# Using a scheduled task with IIS integrated windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have IIS V6 running with "integrated windows authentication" turned on for my website.

I would like to try use the Windows "Task Scheduler" to open a webpage once a night.  The problem is that when the scheduled task runs it displays a pop up asking for a Windows UserID and PW.

I have entered my Windows ID in the "Run as" box in the task scheduler but it still asks for an ID and PW.

Any suggestions on how I can schedule a webpage to open with "integrated windows authentication" turned on?

Note.  the webpage kicks off a nightly batch job.

Thanks!

Comment: I know this is not the answer you want, but why don't you write a Console app that kicks off that job? Whatever the website does can be done from the console app. I think that's a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You probably aren't accessing the site via an intranet address, like http://myservername/default.aspx. By default, Internet Explorer security settings only use pass-through Windows Authentication in the local intranet zone. http://my.local.ip.address/ won't work either; use the local computer name (or server name on the network that doesn't need qualified any), without any dots separating domains.

Comment: I tried http://myservername/default.aspx but still IE asks me to login. I also set task to run as my own user

Comment: @mhesabi Are you using the default IE security settings, or does your domain administrator have them locked down more? Do you have Integrated Windows Authentication installed and enabled on your server? Does it work if you request it locally on that server?